# How to resolve 'package not found' error when building using gradle?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, build.gradle, vnc-viewer

I am trying to build TightVNC Java Viewer from source (I downloaded official version from here: http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php).

When building using provided gradle file, I get this error: package com.jcraft.jsch does not exist.

File 'src/libs/jsch-0.1.50.jar' exists in the project. I cannot figure out why it doesn't compile, since it is included in the build.gradle file. I am building using gradle build command. What am I missing?

This is provided build gradle file, as originally provided in the gradle package:

```
apply plugin:'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
targetCompatibility = 1.6
version = '2.7.2'

project.ext.baseName = 'tightvnc-jviewer'
def buildNo = processBuildNo(version)

defaultTasks 'clean', 'dist'

configurations {
    viewerSwingCompile { extendsFrom compile }
    viewerSwingRuntime { extendsFrom viewerSwingCompile, runtime }
}

sourceSets {
    viewerSwing {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/viewer_swing/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/viewer_swing/resources'
        }
    }
    main {
        java.srcDirs += viewerSwing.java.srcDirs
        resources.srcDirs += viewerSwing.resources.srcDirs
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'src/libs/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    viewerSwingCompile group: 'com.jcraft', name: 'jsch', version: '0.1.+', ext: 'jar'
    viewerSwingRuntime configurations.viewerSwingCompile
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}

def manifestAttributes = ['Main-Class': 'com.glavsoft.viewer.Viewer',
        'Implementation-Version': "${project.version} (${buildNo})",
        'Implementation-Title': 'TightVNC Viewer',
        'Implementation-Vendor': 'GlavSoft LLC.']

jar {
    baseName = project.baseName
    version = null
    manifest {
        attributes manifestAttributes
    }
    def runtimeDeps = configurations.viewerSwingRuntime.collect {
        it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
    }
    from(runtimeDeps) {
        exclude 'META-INF/**'
    }
}

task noSshJar (type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    baseName = 'nossh/' + project.baseName
    version = null
    manifest {
        attributes manifestAttributes
    }
    from sourceSets.main.output
}

artifacts {
    archives file('src/web/viewer-applet-example.html')
    archives noSshJar
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.FileSystemResolver()) {
            addArtifactPattern("$projectDir/dist/${project.baseName}-${project.version}/[artifact].[ext]")
        }
    }
    uploadDescriptor = false
}

task dist(dependsOn: uploadArchives)

def processBuildNo(currentVersion) {
    final String VERSION = 'version'
    final String BUILD = 'build'

    def lastVersion = currentVersion
    def lastBuild = 0
    def buildNoFile = new File('.build_no')
    if ( ! buildNoFile.exists()) {
        buildNoFile.createNewFile()
        buildNoFile << "${VERSION}=${lastVersion}\n${BUILD}=${lastBuild}"
    }
    def versions = [:]
    buildNoFile.eachLine {
        def splitted = it.split('=')
        if (splitted.size() == 2) {
            def (key, value) = splitted
            switch(key.trim()) {
                case VERSION:
                    lastVersion = value.trim()
                    break
                case BUILD:
                    try {
                        lastBuild = value != null ? value.trim() as Integer : 0
                    } catch (NumberFormatException) {}
                    versions[lastVersion] = lastBuild
                    break
            }
        }
    }
    lastVersion = versions[currentVersion]
    if (null == lastVersion) {
        versions[currentVersion] = 0
    }
    ++versions[currentVersion]
    def outString = ''
    versions.each { v, b ->
        outString += "${VERSION}=${v}\n${BUILD}=${b}\n\n"
    }
    buildNoFile.write(outString)
    versions[currentVersion]
}
```

Comment: Best ask the authors/maintainers of this build.

Comment: One thing you can try is to use a fixed version rather than `0.1+`. Also make sure to use the correct Gradle version for the build. Many projects enforce this by shipping the `gradlew` command along with the source code.

Comment: I tried both, no luck. I get the same error. I will contact authors, but I ned to get this working by the end of the weekend if possible.

Comment: I'd also try to remove the `ext: ...` part, and use `mavenCentral()` instead of the `flatDir { ... }` repository.

Comment: Maven is not used. flatdir is used to include a directory where this package (jsch-0.1.50.jar) is located. Removing ext part didn't help.

Comment: My proposal was to try and use Maven Central instead. After all, both declared dependencies are available from there as well.

Comment: Tried it, again no luck :(

Comment: Perhaps the dependency is located successfully (otherwise the error would be different), and it's just some bug in the build. So it's back to asking the authors/maintainers of the build.

Answer (score 1):

After lots of trial and error, I added:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'src/libs', include: '*.jar')
```

under dependencies section and it worked!

Comment: It works. btw, must use gradle 1.x (I used gradle 1.8). gradle 2.x would fail for TightVNC java viewer. And I added the following to the end of file `dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'src/libs', include: '*.jar')
}`